# Multiple parts of methods in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am learning Objective C and noticed this funky quirk while reading up on methods.

Like Java and C++, Obj.C can take in multiple parameters, which is fine, however it states that objective C methods can have multiple names which does not seem to register to well with me.

For instance:

```
-(NSArray *)shipsAtPoint:(CGPoint)bombLocation withDamage:(BOOL)damaged;
```

In the above example, there are two parameters, bombLocation (return type CGPoint) and damaged (return type BOOL) and alongside the method name seems to be split as shipsatpoint:withDamage

I don't understand what's up with this...
What does it signify when it states that a method can have multiple names? 
Is this applicable only for methods that require multiple parameters? Alternately, say I want to name my method with a single name but provide it with multiple parameters, is that possible or I must provide it with multiple names each of which correspond to a parameter? If yes, then why?

Thanks for jumping in with my confusion!!! :)

Comment: Are you sure it was multiple names, not parameters or something else? That's confusing to me as well, as I'm almost certain that methods are defined by one name only.

Comment: nawww...they are defined with multiple names apparently,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is to make it easier to understand.

With your example, the method would be something like this in C++:

```
 int shipsAtPointWithDamage (CGPoint bomb, BOOL damage)  //I don't really know C++
```

OK, so the first parameter is the ship's point, and the damage is the second.  It's easy enough to figure out, but that's the thing, you have to FIGURE it out, you have to look at the method to try and figure out what each thing is.

In Objective-C you have

`-(NSArray *)shipsAtPoint:(CGPoint)bombLocation withDamage:(BOOL)damaged;`

Each parameter is clearly defined, the first is the ship's point, the second is damage.  **It reads like a sentence**, whereas with C++ (and almost every other language) it doesn't.

If you want a method to have multiple parameters in Obj-C you have to write it this way:

`-(returnType)paraOne:(type*)name paraTwo:(type*)name`

It's something that just takes getting used to, every language is different.  Once you get used to the way Objective-C does things, you'll think it's absolutely fantastic.

EDIT: and as filipe pointed out, because the method as multiple parameters it doesn't mean it has multiple names, in the example I gave above, the method name would be `paraOne:paraTwo`, NOT `paraOne:`

Comment: Just to add to that answer, this doesn't mean the method has _multiple names_, just that the `:` is part of the name. So in that example, the name of the method is not simply `shipsAtPoint`, the full name of the method is `shipsAtPoint:withDamage:`

Comment: So Matt, correct me if I am wrong here, the method name is split into multiple names for user readability, they aren't really serving any compiler purpose or provide a unique functionality that methods from other languages such as C++ and Java don't?

Comment: @Parijat from what I understand, this is just a feature that improves readability.  I'm not 100% sure since I'm not an expert, but apple encourages developers to do it that way.  They go out of their way in the Objective-C language documentation to say you can do something like `-(returnType)paraOne:(type*)name :(type*)name` but they explicitly say it's bad style

Answer (score 3):

Objective-C uses a system of message passing based on selectors. This is not quite the same thing as method calling. When you see code like this:

```
[world shipsAtPoint:point withDamage:YES];
```

That is converted into the following C call (in the most common case):

```
objc_msgSend(world, @selector(shipsAtPoint:withDamage:), point, YES);
```

The `@selector()` construct returns a unique identifier. The exact format of that identifier is an internal implementation detail.

`objc_msgSend` includes quite a lot of logic in it's few dozen bytes of assembler. But in simplest case, it looks up the class for `world`, walks through a table of selectors until it finds the one that matches `shipsAtPoint:withDamage:` and then grabs the function pointer at that slot. It then jumps to that function pointer, leaving the rest of the parameters alone (in registers or on the stack as appropriate for the processor). The function at that location is your method, and it knows the order and types of its parameters based on your declaration.

What's important in all this for you is that the selector is `shipsAtPoint:withDamage:`. This is generally the one-and-only name of the method. There are not "multiple names" as you suggest. (Usually.... the Objective-C runtime is very powerful and it's possible to point multiple selectors to the same implementation.)

As Joe points out, a selector can be in the form `foo::`. This would represent a method that took two parameters and would be called like `[world foo:point :YES]`. You should never do this. It's incredibly confusing to read. But it's legal.

Comment: And if you really wanted to, you could call every method using the Objective-C runtime! ಠ_ಠ

Comment: You can, but it's slightly harder than it sounds. If your method returns a floating point or struct, you have to use a different version of `objc_msgSend`. And there's a special version you need to call if you're messaging `super`. The compiler takes care of all of those edge cases for you. If you're using ARC, it's also faster. Currently LLVM seems to want to include an extra retain/release on the return value from an `IMP`, even when the underlying method is `void`. They may fix that in the future.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/method-names-in-objective-c.html) is the best explanation i've ever seen. It includes comparisons with C++/C as well as lots of other good info.

Comment: jesse, I have read through that article before but somehow it never clicked for me, I'll re-read it again anyways, but if you got something else on ya, that would be awesome!

Comment: you can't have 1 method defined with multiple names. Also, there is no "overriding" in objective-c. the parameter names are considered "part" of the method is the best way i can explain it. so `addObject:(id)foo` is a completely different method then `addObject:(id)foo withBar:(id)bar`

Comment: yes but addObject:(id)foo withBar:(id)bar is also the same as
addObjectwithBar:(id)foo:(id)bar;

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confused.  A method cannot have multiple names, but the argument may be named differently in the header then they are in the implementation.

The name of that method is `shipsAtPoint:withDamage:`. This is also known as a `selector`.

This method returns an instance of `NSArray`, and accepts a `CGPoint` as the first argument, and a `BOOL` as the second argument.

The names of the arguments may differ, however.  This is totally valid:

```
// .h file
-(NSArray *)shipsAtPoint:(CGPoint)bombLocation withDamage:(BOOL)damaged;

// .m file
-(NSArray *)shipsAtPoint:(CGPoint)loc withDamage:(BOOL)dmg {
  // ...
}
```

Lastly, ObjC is mainly some nice syntax sugar.  You should know that any method invocation really just boils down to some C that looks more or less like this:

```
objc_msgSend(receiverObj, @selector(shipsAtPoint:withDamage:), point, damage);
```

So at the end of the day, you have a receiver, a selector, and your arguments.  But the ObjC syntax is much nicer than that.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible provide a method without labeled parameters but it is obviously discouraged.

```
-(void)badmethod:(id)obj1:(id)obj2:(id)obj3
{

}

//...
//Usage
[self badmethod:nil :nil :nil];

SEL sel = @selector(badmethod:::);
```